# Team Foundation Error. Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Integration.VssAadVSAccountProvider Credential' in assembly

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I want to build my application in VS 2017 using the XAML build. I know this is being deprecated very soon, in 6 weeks, but I just want to get it working first.
However even using this technique, which has always been straight forward in the past, when I start the process of creating a new build I get this error message;
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Since you are using VS team services, why don't you use vNext build (new build system)? It's easy to use.

Comment: I have run into problems with that. I have asked a separate question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107220/vsts-build-nuget-restore-error-non-whitespace-before-first-tag

Comment: So, do you still need to use XAML build?

Comment: I am thinking it is not worth it. Might as well get the VSTS build to work instead. Just very frustrated with it.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue and there is a feedback reported (check my answer)